# How many five-digit numbers can be formed using the digits 1-9 which have at least three identical digits?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, arithmetic-combinatorics

How many five-digit nos. can be formed using the digits 1-9 having at least three identical digits?

My attempt:

Total no. of possible nos. with no restrictions $=9^5$

No. of numbers having two identical digits$=9\times 8^4$

Hence the answer should be

$( 9^5)-(9\times 8^4) = 22185$

Is this correct? If not then please suggest alternate method.....Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You've forgotten to subtract the possibilities with all different digits.

Comment: Anything else that I missed out? I think the no. of such nos. will be equal to 9×8×7×6×5.....right?

Comment: The number of possible five-digit numbers with no restrictions is $5^9$.

Comment: Thats surely incorrect @ amWhy...It is 9^5.

Comment: Math SE is unusually quite today....seeing only 1 out of every 6-7 questions being answered. Unfortunately....I cant help....I dont much math myself!! Hahaha   ... Note: This comment is is no way related to the question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First approach: Pick which three spots host the identical digits; there are $\binom53$ ways to do this. Fill those three spots in one of $9$ ways, and then fill the other two spots in any of $9$ ways. Thus, $\binom53\times 9^3$

Problem with this approach: the number $12222$ has been counted $4$ times, once as $1\color{red}{222}2$, once as $1\color{red}{22}2\color{red}{2}$, once as $1\color{red}{2}2\color{red}{22}$, and once as $12\color{red}{222}$. Similarly, a number such as $44444$ has been overcounted by a factor of $\binom53$.

This can be fixed by subtracting out the repetitions. There are $5\times 9\times 8$ numbers with exactly $4$ digits identical, and $9$ numbers with exactly $5$ digits identical.

Thus: $\binom53\times 9^3 - (5\times 9\times 8)\times(4-1) - 9\times\left(\binom53 - 1\right)$

This comes out to $7290 - 1080 - 81 = 6129$

---

Doublecheck: Count the numbers with exactly $3$ identical digits, then the ones with exactly $4$, then the ones with exactly $5$:

$\binom53\times 9\times 8\times 8 + \binom54\times 9\times 8 + 9$

which comes out to: $5760 + 360 + 9 = 6129$

Comment: Thanks for the help!! Your doublecheck approach is actually the shortest method to solve....

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why I didn't think of it first.

Comment: Python script shows that the answer is $7371$, which means your anwer is wrong (and so is mine).

Comment: Or else, Python script is wrong.

Comment: How did you code it, exactly?

Comment: Did you remember to exclude the digit $0$?

Comment: Yes. Could be wrong, but I doubt it. It is fairly simple and straightforward.

Comment: I don't know; we obtained the same answer with $3$ different counting methods. That's a heck of a coincidence if it's wrong.

Comment: Why not post your code as an answer, and we'll look at it?

Comment: Taking it back. The script is wrong - I did not count occurrences of $0$, but I did not ignore numbers containing $0$ (so for example, I considered $11100$ as a valid combination). The script confirms your answer, so +1...